# How does this code format the list to the desired output?

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner python student and I'm having trouble with lists.

This was our last weeks' class and I need help understanding how does the commands on this code operate to change the list output.
The commands we were taught on lists and formatting are `split()` , `strip()` , `slice()` , `append()` and `format()`

More spesificly, the part I don't understand exactly is how does the program understand what part are the names and what parts are grades? Where does it split the names from the grades and what do we use the tuple for?

The list given to us is like this

> Hopper, Grace        100   98   87  97
>   Knuth, Donald           82    87  92  81
>   Goldberg, Adele        94   96   90  91
>   Kernighan, Brian      89  74   89  77
>   Liskov, Barbara           87 97   81  85

and the desired output should look like this

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egcnq.png)

The code we wrote in class is:

```
exam1_score = 0
exam2_score = 0
exam3_score = 0
exam4_score = 0
name = ""
scores=[]

f=open("scores.txt","r")

for line in f:
    temp_list = []
    name = line[0:18]
    list = line[19:len(line)].split()

    ex1_score = int(list[0])
    ex2_score = int(list[1])
    ex3_score = int(list[2])
    ex4_score = int(list[3])
    avg_score = float(float(ex1_score+ex2_score+ex3_score+ex4_score)/float(4))

    temp_list.append(name)
    temp_list.append(ex1_score)
    temp_list.append(ex2_score)
    temp_list.append(ex3_score)
    temp_list.append(ex4_score)

    temp_list.append(avg_score)

    scores.append(tuple(temp_list))
    scores = sorted(scores)



print("{:20s}{:6s}{:6s}{:6s}{:6s}{:10s}".format("Name", "Exam1", "Exam2", "Exam3", "Exam4", "Mean"))


ex1_mean = 0
ex2_mean = 0
ex3_mean = 0
ex4_mean = 0
avg_mean = 0

for baslik in scores:
    print ("{:20s}{:6d}{:6d}{:6d}{:6d}{:10.2f}".format(baslik[0],baslik[1],baslik[2],baslik[3],baslik[4],baslik[5]))

    ex1_mean = ex1_mean+baslik[1]
    ex2_mean = ex2_mean+baslik[2]
    ex3_mean = ex3_mean+baslik[3]
    ex4_mean = ex4_mean+baslik[4]
    avg_mean = avg_mean+baslik[5]

print ("{:20s}{:6s}{:6s}{:6s}{:6s}{:10.2s}".format("Exam Mean",str(ex1_mean/len(scores)),str(ex2_mean/len(scores)),str(ex3_mean/len(scores)),str(ex4_mean/len(scores)),str(avg_mean/len(scores))))
f.close()
```

Comment: Programs dont understand what is a name and what is a grade. If you notice, there is `name = line[0:18]` and `list = line[19:len(line)].split()`  Happening in the code. That 18 and 19 are hardcoded, or so called magic numbers. Your examples must have been handpicked to ensure the name portion ends in 18 chars and the number portion starts from 19 onwards.

Comment: Also, please never use the `list` name as a variable name, it is a python keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that each input is on a different line, i.e.

```
Hopper, Grace     100 98 87 97 
Knuth, Donald     82 87 92 81 
Goldberg, Adele   94 96 90 91 
Kernighan, Brian  89 74 89 77 
Liskov, Barbara   87 97 81 85
```

where the first 18 characters include the name, because we have the line:

```
name = line[0:18]
```

Afterwards we split the remaining string with

```
list = line[19:len(line)].split()
```

So, the input is most likely formatted, such that you can hard-code the split of names and grades.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you were never told what strings and characters are.  Understanding those concepts will give you some background info to understand whats going on.

You can think of a word as a string.  The letters in that word are the characters.

An sentence is a string as well.  The only difference between a word and a string is the spaces between the words.  The computer does not care if the character in the string is a space or a letter.  We have to tell the computer to remove the spaces.

So all the split() function does (by default) is separate a sentence on the spaces.  It takes all those words and puts them into a list.

For example, say the last sentence was stored in variable sentence.

In python that would look like:

```
sentence = "It takes all those words and puts them into a list"
```

Now say we just want each word in a list.

```
broken_sentence = sentence.split()
```

The result will be if you print broken_sentence with

```
print(broken_sentence)
```

You will get

```
('It','takes','all','those','words','and','puts','them','into','a','list')
```

Now the computer has a list.  If you want the word It, you access that via index or slicing.

```
print(broken_sentence[0]) will print the FIRST element in the list which is 'It'.
```

Ask your teacher why counting starts with zero in computers, that should be a fun discussion.

Hope this breaks it down a little bit for you.